# Can't plot with x11 or qt in gnuplot in Mac Yosemite

Tags: macos, gnuplot

I can't use "plot" command and get a pop-up window. Gnuplot says "terminal set to unknown. No output will be generated…"

I installed gnuplot with homebrew, first "--with-qt" then tried "--with-x11". Neither of them work. I also installed xquartz. I checked the available terminals, there are no options like "x11""qt"or"png".

Can anybody help me out? Thanks!!!

Comment: Please be sure of which gnuplot you're running, check it with `which gnuplot`. I installed it myself using `brew install gnuplot --with-x11` and it worked. Maybe a `brew reinstall gnuplot --with-x11` ?
I had another problem related to XQuartz with an external monitor that did not X11 windows

Comment: Brew should put it in `/usr/local/bin/gnuplot`

Comment: Yes, but x11 still doesn't appear as an option as terminal

Comment: try with `brew reinstall --build-from-source gnuplot --with-x11`
Otherwise, sorry, no idea...
maybe a `brew update` could help

Comment: Tried it. Now it says: Error: the 'brew link' step did not complete successfully. The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local. Could not symlink share/gnuplot/5.0/PostScript/8859-1.ps. /usr/local/share/gnuplot/5.0/PostScript is not writable. You can again using   brew link gnuplot

Comment: ok, we've found something not working... Good! now try `brew clenup gnuplot` and then `brew uninstall gnuplot --force` and now reinstall with `brew reinstall --build-from-source gnuplot --with-x11`